# android R.id class not found at runtime

Tags: java, android, r.java-file

I m trying to get all ids at runtime. I m using reflection. but i m  getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

```
try {
    aClass = classLoader.loadClass(getPackageName()+".R.id");       
    Field[] ID_Fields = aClass.getFields();
    int[] resArray = new int[ID_Fields.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ID_Fields.length; i++) {    
        try {
          resArray[i] = ID_Fields[i].getInt(null);
         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` is a inner class of `R`. you should use the dollar symbol `$`, to access it

```
classLoader.loadClass(getPackageName()+".R$id");
```

you can also the static method `Class.forName`

```
aClass  = Class.forName(getPackageName()+".R$id");
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with
>   the given string name.